# Comments on non-professional math webpages

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, etiquette

The question is the following:

> Is it allowed to ask for comments
>   about mathematical results found
>   around the net?

I mean, I am not referring to professional articles or preprints (like the ones on [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/)); on the contrary, I'm referring to webpages/documents written by "non-professional mathematicians", whose content isn't usually checked by any reviewer.

For example, recently I stumbled upon a page whose author claimed to have proved *P=NP* in ten lines... And it was crap (obviously); but am I allowed to ask about comments on that page?

Comment: @Moron: Thanks for retagging my question; I was not sure of what tag has to be used.

Comment: You can spare yourself and others the time. 10 line proofs of P=NP that the author is not sending to a journal score so high on the crackpot index that one doesn't need to look at the paper to know that there will be no mathematics in it.

Answer (score 8):

My take is: you can ask mathematical questions.

Comment: Is it a mathematical question to ask *Is the proof of Goldbach conjecture published here* (link) *correct?* or not?

Comment: @Pacciu: yes, but on top of condition of being mathematical there is an implicit need for tact. See <http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/823/deleted-question-about-rosenbergs-proof/> for a similar situation, where great advice is given.

Comment: @Pacciu: Not to mention that you are unlikely to get much interest from such a query unless the link happened to be to a reputable cite and a reputable author...

Comment: @Arturo: I like your pragmatic approach to the question. @Mariano & Arturo: Fair. But, don't you think wrong mathematical opinions can spread around the net even if they comes from that kind of sources? (Say, like a minor infection which becomes gangrene if not cured in time...) And, in the positive case, isn't this a case worth a discussion? I mean, it is totally obvious experienced professional mathematicians cannot believe any ten line proof of *P=NP*, but what about unexperienced guys? Cannot they be badly influenced by those kind of things?

Comment: Ah, the Someone Is Wrong On The Internet phenomenon http://xkcd.com/386/. Well...

Comment: Very nice answer; pragmatic, as I expected.